# spl_autoload_register call function with parameters

Tags: php, parameters, arguments

I have written the following function to load classes:

```
function loadClass($className, $classFolder, $classSuffix=".class.php"){...}
```

Now I want to register 3 autoloaders which are using this function.

```
spl_autoload_register("loadClass"); // Set second variable ($classFolder) to "classes1/"
spl_autoload_register("loadClass"); // Set second variable ($classFolder) to "classes2/"
spl_autoload_register("loadClass"); // Set second variable ($classFolder) to "classes3/"
```

Is there a chance to register an autoloader with an customize second parameter 
(like my 'classes1/' path) without creating a new function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do with:

```
spl_autoload_register(function($className) {
    loadClass($className, "classes1/", $classSuffix=".class.php");
});
spl_autoload_register(function($className) {
    loadClass($className, "classes2/", $classSuffix=".class.php");
});
spl_autoload_register(function($className) {
    loadClass($className, "classes3/", $classSuffix=".class.php");
});
```