# Php, spl_autoload_register pass second parameter

Tags: php, spl-autoload-register

I'm trying to make this work:

```
  function autoload($dir, $className) {
        $filename = $dir . $className . ".php";
        if (file_exists($filename)) {
            include($filename);
            if (class_exists($className)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

  function loader ($dir, $class) {
    spl_autoload_register(array($dir, 'autoload' ));
  }
```

But when using `loader('pathtofile', 'classname');`

I'm getting an error

> Passed array does not specify an existing static method

My question is how can I pass `$dir` variable to `loader` function?

Comment: from a quick glance through the documentation it seems that you can't. A constant or a global variable would work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [spl\_autoload\_register call function with parameters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15184560/spl-autoload-register-call-function-with-parameters)

Answer (score 2):

I hope this is what you need:

```
function loader ($dir) {
    spl_autoload_register(function($class) use ($dir) {
        $filename = $dir . $class . ".php";
        if (file_exists($filename)) {
            include($filename);
            if (class_exists($class)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    });
}

loader('pathtofile');
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are trying to set up your autoloader incorrectly, so I'll stop you there :O. You would want to set a constant which you can use in your function. You should have your autoloader in an included file that will be used in each page loading classes

```
 <?php
  //inc.php

  //Set constant
  define('SOME_DIR','/some/dir');

  spl_autoload_register(function($name){
      if(file_exists(SOME_DIR.$name.'.php')){
          require SOME_DIR.$name.'.php';
      }else{
         echo 'The class '.$name.' could not be found';
      }
 });
 ?>
```

In the file that will be using classes

```
  <?php 
        //top of file
        require 'someDir/inc.php'; 
        //Do something
  ?>
```

Comment: I would like to use a variable within function to set up path dynamically, since each section of script I'm working on will have different path where classes are stored.